# Row_Number partition by id order by timestamp but grouping it by continuous rows

Tags: sql, row-number

Sample Input

```
Name | ID    | Timestamp
-----|-------|-----------------
ABI  | 1     | 2016-01-01 02:00
ABI  | 1     | 2016-01-01 03:00
ABI  | 2     | 2016-01-01 04:00
ABI  | 1     | 2016-01-01 05:00
ABI  | 3     | 2016-01-01 06:00
ABI  | 3     | 2016-01-01 07:00
ABI  | 3     | 2016-01-01 08:00
ABI  | 3     | 2016-01-01 09:00
```

Desired Output

```
Name | ID    | Timestamp       |Rank
-----|-------|-----------------|-----
ABI  | 1     | 2016-01-01 02:00|1
ABI  | 1     | 2016-01-01 03:00|2
ABI  | 2     | 2016-01-01 04:00|1
ABI  | 1     | 2016-01-01 05:00|1
ABI  | 1     | 2016-01-01 06:00|2
ABI  | 3     | 2016-01-01 07:00|1
ABI  | 3     | 2016-01-01 08:00|2
ABI  | 3     | 2016-01-01 09:00|3
```

Attempted Query

I try to use ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITION BY to rank by name and id, but group it by continuous rows sorted by timestamp.

I've tried this one

```
SELECT Name,
       ID,
       TIMESTAMP(_timestamp) AS TimeStamp,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name,ID ORDER BY _timestamp DESC) RANK               
FROM Table_ID
```

but it ranks by name and ID without grouping by continuous rows

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: Your sample data and your expected results do not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  The simplest solution is probably to use the difference of row numbers to identify the groups and then `row_number()` for the final output:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by name, id, seqnum - seqnum_2 order by timestamp) as rank
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by name, id order by timestamp) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use MySql.

You can use `LAG()` and `SUM()` window functions to create the continuous groups and then `ROW_NUMBER()` for each group:

```
SELECT Name, ID, Timestamp,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, grp ORDER BY Timestamp) `Rank`
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Timestamp) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COALESCE(ID <> LAG(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Timestamp), 1) flag
    FROM Table_ID
  ) t  
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m5TuJzc8KcL8YHMtkGJ558/1).

Answer (score 0):

With MariaDB 10.5.0:

```
WITH edges AS (
        SELECT t.*
             , COALESCE(name <> LAG(name) OVER (ORDER BY ts) OR id <> LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY ts), 1) AS edge
          FROM runs AS t
     )
   , grps AS (
        SELECT t.*
             , SUM(edge) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS grp
          FROM edges AS t
     )
SELECT grps.*
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ts) AS actual
  FROM grps
;

+------+------+---------------------+----------+------+------+--------+
| name | id   | ts                  | expected | edge | grp  | actual |
+------+------+---------------------+----------+------+------+--------+
| ABI  |    1 | 2016-01-01 02:00:00 |        1 |    1 |    1 |      1 |
| ABI  |    1 | 2016-01-01 03:00:00 |        2 |    0 |    1 |      2 |
| ABI  |    2 | 2016-01-01 04:00:00 |        1 |    1 |    2 |      1 |
| ABI  |    1 | 2016-01-01 05:00:00 |        1 |    1 |    3 |      1 |
| ABI  |    1 | 2016-01-01 06:00:00 |        2 |    0 |    3 |      2 |
| ABI  |    3 | 2016-01-01 07:00:00 |        1 |    1 |    4 |      1 |
| ABI  |    3 | 2016-01-01 08:00:00 |        2 |    0 |    4 |      2 |
| ABI  |    3 | 2016-01-01 09:00:00 |        3 |    0 |    4 |      3 |
+------+------+---------------------+----------+------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Note: I ran into a bug which prevented using something a little more readable: ```(name, id) <> (LAG(name) OVER ... , LAG(id) OVER ...)```